# showing paging number in URL in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-4.0, datapager

Is it possible to show paging number in url in asp.net 4.0?

i have a listview and datapager and i am using Url routing.
So when page load showing first page of listview then i want url to be

```
http://www.shop.com/book/1
```

and paging is done for second page then

```
http://www.shop.com/book/2
```

if possible then please guide me.

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify the templates for the Datapager to adjust how to renders the URL. This [article on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.templatepagerfield.aspx) has a lot of detail.